# Azure SQL - Single or multiple DB connections?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I have client-server application, where server side is Azure WCF service with data in SQL azure database. Clients are Windows Phone 7 silverlight applications. Client and server communicate throught WCF. Server is providing data to client which are stored in Azure SQL database.

I recently ran to some problems with pooling. I was creating new object every time when client request arrived. I was not closing this connections and very soon encountered exception:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a
>   connection from the pool.  This may have occurred because all pooled
>   connections were in use and max pool size was reached.

My question is - how should connection object to DB be handled? Should i create one connection object for every client request or should i create singleton object which should handle all calls to db? IS it even possible - does not connection object time out after some time or something?

I am using SQLConnection object:

```
private static SqlConnection connection
        {
            get
            {
                SqlConnectionStringBuilder connectionStringBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
                {
                    DataSource = DB_SOURCE,
                    InitialCatalog = DB_NAME,
                    Encrypt = false,
                    TrustServerCertificate = false,
                    UserID = DB_USER,
                    Password = DB_PASS,
                };
                SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());
                c.Open();
                return c;
            }
        }

        public static void execute(String query)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the answers provided by Wiktor Zychla, Tobias, and Herve Roggero.  They explain that:

1. Your getter (`connect` property), doesn't return the original `SqlConnection` that you were expecting, hence the original connection is not getting closed.
2. You should create `SqlConnection`s when you need them, keep them open only as long as you need them, and close them when you are done.

Here's a complete solution:

```
private static string _connectionString = string.Empty;

private static string connectionString
{
  get
  {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connectionString))
    {
      _connectionString = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
      {
        DataSource = DB_SOURCE,
        InitialCatalog = DB_NAME,
        Encrypt = false,
        TrustServerCertificate = false,
        UserID = DB_USER,
        Password = DB_PASS,
      }.ToString();
    }

    return _connectionString;
  }
}

public static void Execute(String query)
{
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
  {
    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```

Comment: If i am using "using" like described above, i do not need to call connection.close(), right?

Comment: Correct; `using` guarantees that `connection.Close()` gets called when it goes out of scope (http://www.w3enterprises.com/articles/using.aspx).  In fact, I'm downvoting Wiktor's answer, because his code is bad!  *The point he makes is correct though.*

Answer (score 1):

SQL connections are pooled by default.  Therefore you should "create" them when you need them and destroy them when done.  (Your code will be simpler if you use `using` rather than `try/finally`.)

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the `connection` twice in your code and because of that you have **two** different connections, as your `get`ter always creates a new connection!

Thus, the latter is created and then immediately disposed but the former one is not closed.

Rewrite your code at least to:

```
public static void execute(String query) {
    SqlConnection c = null;
    try { 
      c = connection;
      using ( SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, c);                 
         com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally {
       if ( c!=null)
         c.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work since the getter of `connection` might throw an exception and then `c` would be _anything_, which is a state the compiler doesn't like, for obvious reasons...

Comment: Right. The check would be nice.

Comment: You are still not initializing `c`. And local variables aren't automatically set to the default value, so the compiler will still complain about the possibility of `c` not being initialized at first reading attempt (but the check for `null` is definitely not bad)...

Comment: Don't have the compiler at hand thus I make basic omissions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not closing the connection you used for the command but a new one you created just for closing it.

The body of your `execute` method should be as follows:

```
var con = connection;
try 
{ 
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con); 
    com.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
} 
finally 
{ 
    con.Close(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One connection per request is way too many connections. (the one extreme)
Singleton connection is way too few connections.

What you need is to have a connection per user session.
The easiest way to do that is by using IoC container, like Ninject and request your connection via the container.

Comment: Right now i have no mechanism to maintain sessions. This wcf communication is more like fire and forget - each request is separate. Time between requests from one client can be between under second to many minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Oliver that you should create connections and close them every time; connection pooling will handle the rest for you. Also you should keep your connections open to a minimum amount of time. Closing your connections every time, as quickly as possible, and making sure your connection string is the same very time ensures your connection pooling strategy will work.